# How to obtain the quadratic equation when given that the sum of the roots at equal to 47 and the product of the roots is -59?

Tags: proof-verification, systems-of-equations

There is a certain question in which the sum of the solutions (roots) of a quadratic equation is given which is 47, as well as the product of solutions, which  is -59. The formulas for the sum and product of two real distinct roots are:

```
x1 + x2 = -b / a
x1 * x2 = c / a
```

Also, the question recommended using:

```
x1^2 + x2^2 = (b^2 - 2*a*c) / a^2
```

After using,:

```
47 = -b / a
b = -47*a
```

And,:

```
59 = c / a
c = -59*a
```

Substituting these into:

```
x1^2 + x2^2 = (b^2 - 2*a*c) / a^2
```

I get:

```
2327 = x1^2 + x2^2
```

Now, I have:

```
x1 + x2 = 47
x1 * x2 = -59
x1^2 + x2^2 = 2327
```

I am not sure what to do next, to get the values of a, b, c. I tried substituting different equations into others but there was no result in isolating for variable and getting its value. I was wondering what next steps I should take to isolate and get the values of a, b, and c for the quadratic equation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is standard: two numbers $x_1, x_2$ with a sum $s$ and product $p$ are the roots of the quadratic equation
$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=x^2-sx+p=0. $$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I just want to clarify that, I did not have to use any third expression or solve anything, just that the equation you told in the answer and then you substitute in s = 47 and p = -59. Also, this question is related to proofs, so I was wondering how would I be able to get the equation you said in the your answer? Thank you

Comment: @Strikers Expand the left-hand side of that equation and collect terms.

Comment: Hi amd. Okay I expanded as you have suggested, and I end up with x^2 - x(x1+x2) + x1x2. And I see that this gives the equation with x1+x2 = 47 and x1 * x2 = -59 -> x^2 - 47x -59. In this the answer? Also, how would I come up with (x-x1)(x-x2) for the start with information only given in the question? Thank you.

Comment: @Strikers: Yes the equation is $x^2-47x-59=0$. As to your your second question, it's obvious a quadratic equation with roots $x_1,x_2$, is $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=0$, and it happens that, expanding the l.h.s., it can be expressed  with $s$ and $p$.

Comment: Okay thank you. Also one last question, what do you mean by the answer is 'standard'? Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers: When I began high school, it was a theorem about quadratic equations. Nowadays, I believe it's a least an exercise every student has seen (dependeing on the curriculum, of course). So I consider this resulyt as ‘standard’.